# CORS error on localhost, Is that a normal?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am running a node.js API on port 8000 which is connected locally to mongo db.

I then start my react server on port 3000 and straight away in console I get the error:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8000/api/hero/' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Is this normal for a localhost setup?

Comment: Access-Control-Allow-Origin block all request, that are not defined in your node.js API https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Comment: Cross-Origin Resource Sharing when you request some data from one origin `http://localhost:3000` to another `http://localhost:8000/api/hero/`
It won't happen if you will have request from `http://localhost:8000/` to `http://localhost:8000/api/hero/` because they are same origin

Comment: @Arseniy-II, I can't run node.js and react both on the same port

Comment: I am sure you can. But you may not. It is up to you. If you wish to have different ports you will need to add cross origin headers to your response as Janneck Lange has suggested to you

Comment: You can google 'node cors error'. You will have a lot of answers. Here on of the first results https://daveceddia.com/access-control-allow-origin-cors-errors-in-react-express/

Comment: @Arseniy-II, I tried with the same port and then react just fails to work with cannot GET/ message

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, because CORS doesn't care about `localhost` in any specific way. Instead, the combination (!) of hostname and port is being used to differ between multiple parties.

Hence, for CORS, `localhost:3000` is something completely different than `localhost:8000`, so, *yes*, this is normal.

Answer (score 3):

I guess localhost:3000 is running webpack dev server? If so the simplest way to resolve this is to config your webpack dev server to proxy the request for you, so no need to add CORS handling on your own express server

in your webpack.conf.js, add

```
devServer: {
  proxy: {
    '/api': 'http://localhost:8000'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Access-Control-Allow-Origin block all request, that are not defined in your node.js API

Add the following lines to your node.js server. This allows you to access the api from every url.

```
    this.app.use(function (req, res, next) {
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, authorization");
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
        next();
    });
```

Comment: great answer thank you so much